# USB to TTL with switchable 5v and 3.3v in one

Tags: usb

are there any USB to TTL with switchable 5v and 3.3v

i need to use it for raspberry pi and arduino

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many 3.3V FTDI based devices are 5V tolerant and will work with both:

- [Adafruit's FTDI friend](https://www.adafruit.com/product/284)
- [Sparkfun FT231X Breakout](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11736)

Here is general information about logic levels: https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/logic-levels

Comment: so the HIGH for arduino is 3v to 5v and LOW is 0v to 1.5v , can i used USB to 3.3v TTL for both arduino and RPI

Comment: Yes, in general 3.3V logic output is compatible with 5V input.  Some, *but not all* 3.3V devices are tolerant of 5V input. Check the datasheets to be sure. Always be careful when combining 3.3V logic and  5V logic it is possible to damage components.